# How to add page in menu in wordpress

Tags: navigation, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm first time in WordPress and I want to edit the navigation.. I want to add some pages since the only list in my theme is 'Home and Sample Page' which is I think is default for all themes. How can I do that thing? And how can I change into horizontal the navigation menu? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: first find the menu id using a web inspector. Then find a style.css or some related name file and modify the css so the menu is navigation menu

Comment: I can't find. Please tell me the exact location or file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Navigate to Appearance->Menu on page section click on view alll you can see you rest of page and add the Good luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all go to your `wp-admin`

And navigate to `Appearance --> Menus`

There you will find default menus or custom menus...

You also can create your custom menus there,

after adding pages/links to your menu, select the `Theme locations` below the menus and hit `Save Menu`...

Now you are done.!!

Comment: it's not working. The page is didn't add. I still have 2 pages 'Home and Sample Page'

Comment: have you select checkbox named `Theme locations` ????
Options will be like `Primary Menu`, `Main Menu`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution:

You can change menu setting under: 
**Appearance->Menu section** (In admin).
Here you can easily change menu or add custom page, custom link easily.

Comment: it's not working. The page is didn't add. I still have 2 pages 'Home and Sample Page'